# Functional C++11 strange behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, function-pointers

Why this line doesn't compile:

```
function<const int&(const int&, const int&)> min_ptr = min<int>;
```

But this works fine:

```
const int &(*min_ptr)(const int&, const int&) = min<int>;
```

It would seem that function class is flexible and comfortable replacement for function pointers. But why this case doesn't work?

**EDIT**. My code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int&(*min_ptr)(const int&, const int&) = min<int>; //It is works fine
    function<const int&(const int &, const int&)> min_f = min<int>;// Doesn't compile
    /*
       Error message:
        error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type 
        ‘std::function<const int&(const int&, const int&)>’ requested function<const int&(const int &, const int&)> min_f = min<int>;
    */
    return 0;
}
```

gcc version 4.8.2, --std=c++11

Comment: Real program please, and real error messages. Could be as simple as missing `std::`.

Comment: indeed, it compiles for me with `using namespace std;`

Comment: Compiler, version and flags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assignment to

```
const int &(*min_ptr)(const int&, const int&)
```

also casts the `min<int>` to a particular signature.  The cast to `std::function` does not.

Add

```
 static_cast<const int &(*)(const int&, const int&)>
```

to the `std::function` assignment to get it to work.

```
auto* min_ptr = min<int>;
```

also fails to work.

There is more than one overload of `min<int>` to consider.

```
std::function<const int&(const int &, const int&)> min_ptr =
  [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
    return min<int>(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
```

also works in C++14.

Comment: But *why* doesn't cast to std::function cast min<int> to a particular signature?

Comment: @REACHUS the issue that the [`std::function` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) takes anything under the sun.

Comment: But why after declaring variable `min_ptr` with fixed type compiler can't automatically cast right argument to this type?

Comment: @nikita There are many 'why' questions.  Why is it designed that way?  What steps under the standard lead to that result?  Why do they not modify the standard to make it work?  Why do slightly different, yet seemingly identical, situations work?